# jquery selection of @import url()

Tags: jquery, css, refresh

https://github.com/NV/auto_update_stylesheets

I am trying to update this great script to work with cruel css imports like:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://192.168.1.238/system.base.css");
</style>
```

The script only works for normal inclusions of css like:

```
<link href="stylesheets/bundle_github.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I understand the logic of this script but my problem is how can I select `@import url ('foo')`, the part inside the `url()`, in this sample `foo`. If I know if this is even possible I could fix my problems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a good cross-browser way of doing this. See [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#access) for details about the way browsers implement CSS rules.

You'll have to identify the correct way to get an `@import` rule in order to parse it.

For IE, you'll need to get `document.styleSheets[0].imports[0]` assuming the first `style` or `link rel="stylesheet"` reference on your page contains the `@import` rule as its first rule. Looks like you need to call `document.styleSheets[0].removeImport(0);` and `document.styleSheets[0].addImport("URL");` to modify.

Other browsers would seem to use `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0]` assuming the same structure. For those you'll need to use `document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule(0)` and `document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('@import url("URL")')`. Those are standard DOM Level 2 rules; see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleSheet).

Hope that helps.

Comment: so i need to do it with plain JS and there is no jquery way?

Comment: Correct. jQuery doesn't expose any way of dealing with stylesheets or rules. It only deals with adding/removing classes and inline style attributes.